# How to know when observables in observableArray change (knockoutJS)?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have an observableArray of a data structure I created, and in this data structure, one of the fields is an observable. How can I keep track of when the values of the inner observables (inside the data structure) will change? I have tried to subscribe the inner variable, but that did not work.

Comment: Provide some code and possibly a fiddle to demonstrate the structure you created. If you subscribed to it and bound it to the view properly, it should have worked.

Comment: It would also be very helpful if you state why you want to subscribe to observables stored in an observableArray so that we can think of alternative solutions.

Comment: If you access the inner observable from a computed that computed will resolve all observables in chain

Answer (score 0):

I set up a fiddle to mimic your situation. It consists of a view model that has an `ko.observableArray` , and each item in the array contains `ko.observable` properties. Assuming you have defined functions to create the objects in your data structure, you can place a `subscribe` function within each of them.

Here's the [link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gDZWR/1/)

The code:

```
function luggage(data) {
    var self = this;
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.color = ko.observable(data.color);
    this.color.subscribe(function (newvalue) {
        console.log(self.id() + ' changed!');
    });
}

function vm() {
    this.train = ko.observableArray():
}
```